# Pandas concat behaves different now

Tags: pandas, concatenation, python-3.12

I have two python/anaconda environments with juypter notbooks.
No. 1

- Python 3.11.5
- Pandas 2.1.1
- Jupyter 6.5.4

No. 2

- Python 3.12
- Pandas 2.1.1
- Jupyter 7.0.6

Basically, I have a quite simple task to join two DataFrames with

`pd.concat(["buffer", "new"])`

buffer has the shape
(1979444, 10)

and dtype:
shop                    object
kat1                    object
kat2                    object
kanal                   object
device                  object
datum           datetime64[us]
brutto                 float64
sales                  float64
menge                  float64
wareneinsatz           float64
dtype: object

new has shape
(44040, 10)

and dtype
shop                    object
kat1                    object
kat2                    object
kanal                   object
device                  object
datum           datetime64[ns]
brutto                 float64
sales                  float64
menge                  float64
wareneinsatz           float64
dtype: object

but I changed that.

No. 1 works fine but with No. 2 I get this error message, although both use the same script:

**ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 1979444 and the array at index 1 has size 44040**

It looks like the DataFrames changed dimensions/rows and columns but I dont know why. Any idea? Its the same Pandas Version so I dont think its a new "feature".

Summary
Same Script, same machine but different environments with Python 3.12 instead of 3.11.5 but same Pandas Version so I expected same outcome.

At first, columns had a different sequence and two cols were formated as int not floats but I fixed that.

I can switch back to the older installation but somewhere in time I will have to update Python and it would be nice if it would work then.

Comment: It's surprising that the same pandas version and different python/jupyter would trigger this error. Are you sure you tested with the same dataset? Please provide a minimal reproducible example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I don't know exactly, but it might help you.(axis = 1): pd.concat([series1, series2], axis = 1). Show us the exact dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

I was able to narrow it down to a date column. Look both the same but the first df was formated as:
datum    datetime64 **[ns]**

the second as:
datum    datetime64 **[us]**

Works with python 3.11.5 but not 3.12 - tested it outside of Jupyter. Didnt find it before because the error message does not really make sense:

**ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 6), indices imply (4, 6)**

Thanks for helping me thinking! ;)

Comment: OMG, thank you so much!!! I have been struggling with this for days. This should be flagged as a breaking change in Python 3.12... code that has been working for years all of a sudden started failing.... and talk about a misleading Error message.

Comment: While I am whingeing, the following is not a fix : ```df["TIME"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TIME"], utc=True, unit='us')```   If ```df["TIME"]``` is ```datetime64[ns, UTC]``` before the call to ```pd.to_datetime``` then it will remain in nanoseconds. This works: ```df["TIME"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TIME"], utc=True, unit='us').dt.as_unit('us')```